# How to ensure that a Struct that is made up of channels and map gets passed by reference?

Tags: dictionary, go, struct, pass-by-reference, go-map

I have the following struct that contains channels and a map for storage of data. I want to be able to pass that struct into functions in order to make use of those channels so that once they are triggered/have incoming messages, to use them in order to update the map that is associated with it.

I understand that maps by default are passed by reference when sent to various functions. Would this be the same case even when they are contained within a custom struct? How do i make sure that my entire struct is passed around to functions by reference in order to update Storage and also make use of its channels?

```
type CustomStrct struct {
Storage      map[string]string
RetrieveChannel    chan string
InsertChannel      chan string
}
```

This is a constructor I have created for initialising a new instance of the struct:

```
func InitializeNewStore() CustomStrct {
    newCustomStruct := CustomStrct {
        Storage:      make(map[string]string),
        RetrieveChannel:    make(chan Request),
        InsertChannel:    make(chan Request),
       }
 
return newCustomStruct 
}
```

Comment: Go does not have value references. To achieve what you want, pass a pointer to your strict. A go map is essentially a pointer.

Comment: I had just thought of that while typing up my question . Does that mean that I should be passing variables into my constructor and creating a new instance of my Struct using those passed in variables ?

Comment: For example : m:= make(map[string]string ) c1:= make(chan string ). NewStruct := InitializeNewStore(m,c1) ?

Comment: Your constructor is fine. Channels & maps need to be initialized & doing it there before the `struct` is used, is the perfect place it.

Comment: I appreciate your help but unfortunately I’m not following what you’re saying . Could you please show me via a code example ?

Comment: Channel and map values are a single internal pointer.  That internal pointer does not change no matter how the value is passed around (in a struct field or some other way).  The code in InitializeNewStore is a good example of how to initialize the channels and maps before the struct is used.

Comment: @BaytaDarell So if I wanted to add a value to the map in my struct would the following function work? :   func AddToMap(cs *CustomStruct){ cs.Storage["foo"]="foo" }

Comment: Yes, that function works.  This function also works:  `func AddToMap(cs CustomStruct){ cs.Storage["foo"]="foo" }`.  The key point to understand is that maps and channels are internally a pointer. The pointer can be copied and still refer to the channel or map's data.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help and information ! :)

Comment: Do make sure you synchronized access to any maps. Either an individual sync.Mutex for each map or one single mutex for the entire struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slices, maps and channels are *pointer-like* values in Go: copying a struct containing a channel copies a reference to the channel, not the channel itself:

```golang
a := CustomStrct{
    RetrieveChannel: make(chan Request),
}
b := a
log.Println(a.RetrieveChannel == b.RetrieveChannel)    // logs true
```

So it's quite fine to pass your struct either by value or by reference.

If you need to ensure that `go vet` will flag attempts to pass your struct by value, the simplest solution is to embed a `sync.Mutex` inside the struct:

```
type CustomStrct struct {
    mu sync.Mutex
    ...
}
```

You don't need to actually use the mutex: just having it embedded in the struct will cause `go vet` to complain whenever you attempt to pass it by value.